# zcat a file line by line?

Tags: files, compression, gzip

I have written a C++ application that reads files line by line. It reads one line, does processing, then reads the next line.

I would like to add support for gzipped files, and am looking to an alternative to using C++ decompression libraries. One solution is to decompress the entire file, then read it as usual.

However, I'm dealing with very large files and I prefer the quick start-up time `zcat` provides by immediately decompressing the first lines of the file. The problem is that, left unchecked, `zcat` would decompress too much of the file too quickly for my application to keep up and the output buffer from the system command would quickly fill with a decompressed 10GB file while my application is still processing the first few lines.

Is it possible to pause `zcat`, or tell it to only read one line at a time, only advancing when the user indicates?

Comment: You are doing it wrong. You need to read up on basic concepts of Linux/Unix/POSIX. The first concept you need is a *[pipe](http://www.linfo.org/pipes.html)*.

Comment: @n.m. I understand how pipes work in Linux, and that they have a capability similar to what I am looking for here in that if I `zcat | someCommand`, that `zcat` will only provide what `someCommand` is looking for. Is there a `someCommand` you are aware of that would actually answer my question?

Comment: Your application *is* `someCommand`.

Comment: If you don't want the user to type `zcat |`, you can use `popen(2)` system call to create the same thing from within your application.

Comment: oops... a correction: `popen` is not a system call, that would be `popen(3)` library function.

Comment: Programming questions are off-topic; you can ask about programming on [so]. But really you're overcomplicating things, you're just looking for the `popen` function.

Answer (score 3):

Quoted below from the manual page of [pipe(7)](http://linux.die.net/man/7/pipe).

> **Pipe capacity**
>
> A pipe has a limited capacity. If the pipe is full, then a write(2)
>   will block or fail, depending on whether the O_NONBLOCK flag is set
>   (see below). Different implementations have different limits for the
>   pipe capacity. Applications should not rely on a particular capacity:
>   an application should be designed so that a reading process consumes
>   data as soon as it is available, so that a writing process does not
>   remain blocked.
>
> In Linux versions before 2.6.11, the capacity of a pipe was the same
>   as the system page size (e.g., 4096 bytes on i386). Since Linux
>   2.6.11, the pipe capacity is 65536 bytes.

The pipe has a specific capacity, probably 64k for modern linux kernel. If that capacity is reached, any writes are blocked until it some room is available after a read call. So, generally, `zcat your_file.gz | your_program` would only have 64k uncompressed at any given time and so you shouldn't worry about memory usage.

Comment: The thing is, my program is the thing that is doing the `zcat` via a system call. So it doesn't actually use the `|` character. But I do wonder if this is still applicable to the `popen` syscall mentioned in the comments by n.m.

Comment: @CoryKlein This is a property of the pipe feature, which is what the `|` character in the shell triggers. It equally applies to other methods of creating pipes such as `popen`.

Answer (score 1):

If your application is only setup to read files and not `stdin`, you can use process substitution. It will function in a similar manor as a pipe, but the shell will present it to your application as a file. This feature is available in most modern shells, but is not POSIX. Here is an example:

```
yourscript <(zcat filename)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [pv](http://www.ivarch.com/programs/pv.shtml) to rate limit the data you pipe to zcat.

```
pv -L 5k -q < test.gz | zcat
```

Comment: That's irrelevant, `zcat <test.gz` will do just as well (except for not being bound by the completely arbitrary rate of 5kB/s).